# Power Settings Command Line Tool High CPU Usage

Tags: azure, windows-server-2022

For the last few days, one of our Windows servers (Windows Server 2022 Datacentre Azure Edition) has suddenly started running rather slow. On inspection, "Power Settings Command-Line Tool" is sitting using 60-80% CPU usage.

The server in question is an azure server.

Is there a way to disable this command line tool? We dont use power profiles on the machine

Answer (score 1):

You can replace powercfg.exe (Power Settings Command Line Tool) with any executable that goes to 100% utilization and hangs.

Yes, you may terminate the process.

If you do not want processes to run the executable, you need to add a Deny:Execute ACE to the file permissions.  (This permission change would prevent changing the power plan).

I believe this is related to `powercfg.exe /requests` and how certain vendors are using this command.